# react-select CreatableSelect dont allow numbers

Tags: react-select

How can I not allow a user to type numbers on my CreatableSelect component?

```
                   <CreatableSelect              
                    onKeyDown={handleNumberInput}
                    components={animatedComponents}
                    isSearchable={true}
                    isMulti
                    options={selectTags}            
                    onChange={newTagsSelectedfunction}
                  />
```

I'm trying to do it with **onKeyDown** but wonder if it could accept a pattern property

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by accessing the key property of the event

```
const handleNumberInput = (e) => {
    if (Number.isInteger(Number(e.key))) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  };
```